# How to split tables in HTML string into string collection using apex?

Tags: apex

I have a HTML data in string format and i need to split the HTML string by using Regex pattern matcher and get the tables into list of strings.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../javascript/master.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../javascript/fusioncharts/FusionCharts.js"></script>
</head>
<title>Copy of Daily Flow Summary</title>
<body>
<div id="reportDetail">

    <div id="reportHeader">
        <h1>Copy of Daily Flow Summary</h1>
        <span style="padding-left: 3px;"></span>
    </div>


    <h3 >
        <br />
        <b><span>Report Period:</span></b>
        02/14/2018 - 02/14/2018
    </h3>



    <h3 >
        <br />
        <b><span>Run Date:</span></b>
        02/14/2018
    </h3>

<br/>

<div id="reportGraph" style="z-index: 0;width:100%"></div>





<div id="reportData">



    <div xmlns:pd4ml="http://pd4ml.com" class="pdfHidden"><img src="/pw/images/s.gif" height="50px">

<table class="statementHeaderTable">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="statementHeaderTable">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried using the below code and when i hardcode the above html content in the responseBody string, i am able to get the tables correctly but when i try to use the same code with the html content retrieved via url, it doesn't find any match.

```
String responseBody = response.getBody();
String TableExpression = '<table[^>]*>(.*?)</table>';
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile(TableExpression);
Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(responseBody);
while(myMatcher.find()){
        System.debug('my Matcher : ' + myMatcher.group());
        }
```

I think the issue is due to the html string returned via url has multilines because when i remove the "RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase" values from the below c# code, it doesn't give any result. Can anyone suggest me an alternative to these options in apex?

I am able to get the same result in c# using the below code.

```
string html = "html string retrieved via url";
string TableExpression = "<table[^>]*>(.*?)</table>";
MatchCollection Tables = Regex.Matches(HTML, TableExpression, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: [Dont parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Making a second comment because I want to leave something constructive & I cant edit my other comment, try using [Apex's XML Support](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm) to read this html instead.

Comment: @battery.cord Is there any sample in apex about how to parse using XML?

Comment: The [streams example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_streaming_reading.htm) is a little more relevant, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675702/basic-xml-parsing-issues-cannot-find-node-names-via-java-xmlstreamreader-method/13686520#13686520) is old but seems worth looking at, [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/134214/apex-how-to-get-all-child-element-of-an-xml-parsing-xml-via-xmlstreamreader) also.

Comment: @battery.cord Thanks for providing the url of Apex's xml support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `myPattern.matcher()` just creates a `Matcher` object you can use to match against the string. You need to call [methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm) on the `Matcher` to actually get back match data. For example, something like

```
while (myMatcher.find()) {
    String thisGroup = myMatcher.group();
    // do something with this group, add to a List, etc.
}
```

would allow you to iterate through the matched tables.

Differences that you observe in behavior between hard-coded and web-sourced HTML are very case-specific, being dependent on the specific HTML and your regex. This would require a specific reproducible example to attempt to address.

Comment: I tried adding '(?m)(?i)(?s)' to the pattern and now i am getting the desired output.

Comment: @Ean You can combine flags. Use `(?mis)` instead. Although `m` and `s` conflict, so only `s` is applied. Use `(?is)`.

Comment: @Adrian Larson Thanks Adrian. I have combined the flags now.